# Where does Google Chrome fetch policy information?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os

At `chrome://policy/`, you can see various things set by your device administrator. Where does Google Chrome fetch these? Based off of the information under `Device Policies` and `User Policies`, can I get the URL where it fetches it?

I have tried looking through Chromium source code, but I am guessing it is not there because Chrome and Chromium are different, and the `chrome/browser/chromeos/policy/` folder is giant and I don't know C.